# How to filter columns in Excel based on cell values

Tags: microsoft-excel

In rows 1-300 there are entries in columns J - AV which are either `pass` or `fail`. I would like to mark column AW as `fail` if any 1 cell in a column contains `fail`, and `pass` if no cells in that column contain `fail`.

But if a column has `FAIL: V2126` or `Fail: V1111` then it isn't an exact match to `fail` it's being taken (incorrectly) as pass. How can I make it recognize this as fail, as well?

Comment: If you have cells that *contain* the word `fail`, but are not equal to `fail` (in their entirety), you should [edit] you question and say so.  (Actually, you should have said so from the beginning, when you posted the question.)

Comment: Do you have 2 conditions for the cell AW? 1. J-AV all PASS and V2126 or V 11111 Fail? Could you provide a simple sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a formula:

`=IF(COUNTIF(J1:AV1,"fail")>0,"fail","pass")`

If your cells contains other text too, then you can use wildcards:

`=IF(COUNTIF(J1:AV1,"*fail*")>0,"fail","pass")`